# gfxCardStatus set preferences by application

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, gpu

I use Adobe Connect for online classes, but for some reason it wants to use the discreet graphics in my 2011 MBP. I installed `gfxCardStatus` to force Integrated Only, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can limit the Adobe Connect application itself to Integrated, or at least write a script to force Integrated Only before launching the app.

I've written an email to the development team letting them know that Adobe Connect doesn't need the discreet GPU. They probably won't do anything, but it's work a shot.